# Iceweasel very slow when running youtube fullscreen

Tags: pi-3, web-browsers, youtube

I am using RPi3, with Raspbian minimal + i3wm + iceweasel, with a 1080p monitor. When I watch youtube (720p, about 1.5 hour long), if not full screen everything runs just fine. However, once I switch to full screen, the loading becomes extremely slow, and Pi gets stuck every few seconds. Is there anything wrong with the hardware? Or is this expected? I heard Pi can run 1080p movies without problems, but why 720p youtube gets problematic once it's fullscreen.

Comment: I know downloading sounds like a sour option, but you might want to look into the `pythong-pafy` package, which includes `ytdl` which *I'm guessing* is the current incarnation of `yt`, which will save the file as an `.mp4` and can be played back fullscreen via oxmplayer.  There might even be something in there to buffer/stream (or if you are handy enough, there's a potential way to cobble that).  I haven't used yt in a few years though and can't provide a full answer.